# valores num hashmap

Tags: java

Gente, tenho esse código, ele pega uma frase e conta quanto tempo demorou para digitar uma frase inteira. dado que cada letra tem uma valor. mas eu tenho que fazer isso para 10 frases. e eu só estou conseguindo se eu repetir código, por exemplo, eu coloco: frase1, frase2 .... até frase 10 e repito todo o resto de código, ou seja, um for para cada frase, um count para cada frase...  Eu quero saber se há como reaproveitar o código para as 10 frases, sem precisar criar 10 "for" e 10 count?

```
package pacote;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class ContagemMelhoria2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashLetras=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    hashLetras.put("A", 2); hashLetras.put("E", 3); hashLetras.put("O", 3); hashLetras.put("S", 4); hashLetras.put("R", 4); 

    hashLetras.put("I", 4); hashLetras.put("N", 5); hashLetras.put("D", 5); hashLetras.put("M", 5); hashLetras.put("U", 5); 

    hashLetras.put("T", 6); hashLetras.put("C", 6); hashLetras.put("L", 6); hashLetras.put("P", 6); hashLetras.put("V", 7); 

    hashLetras.put("G", 7); hashLetras.put("H", 7); hashLetras.put("Q", 7); hashLetras.put("B", 8); hashLetras.put("F", 8); 

    hashLetras.put("Z", 8); hashLetras.put("J", 9); hashLetras.put("X", 9); hashLetras.put("K", 9); hashLetras.put("W", 10);

    hashLetras.put("Y", 10);hashLetras.put(" ", 6);//espaco


    String frase1 = "TECNOLOGIA ENVOLVE SERVICO RECURSOS ESTRATEGIA";

    int count=0;

    for(int i=0; i<frase1.length();i++){

        if( i<(frase1.length()-1) && frase1.charAt(i)=='Q' && frase1.charAt(i+1)=='U'){
             count = count+8;
             i++;
        }else{
            String c = frase1.charAt(i)+ "";
            count = count+hashLetras.get(c);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("O tempo foi de: "+count);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi! Você pode criar um método auxiliar para fazer isso para você.

Segue um exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String frase1 = "TECNOLOGIA ENVOLVE SERVICO RECURSOS ESTRATEGIA";
        String frase2 = "TECNOLOGIA ENVOLVE SERVICO RECURSOS ESTRATEGIA E AERODINAMICA";

    System.out.println(contaLetras(frase1));
    System.out.println(contaLetras(frase2));

    }

    private static String contaLetras(String frase) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> hashLetras=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        hashLetras.put("A", 2); hashLetras.put("E", 3); hashLetras.put("O", 3); hashLetras.put("S", 4); hashLetras.put("R", 4); 
        hashLetras.put("I", 4); hashLetras.put("N", 5); hashLetras.put("D", 5); hashLetras.put("M", 5); hashLetras.put("U", 5); 
        hashLetras.put("T", 6); hashLetras.put("C", 6); hashLetras.put("L", 6); hashLetras.put("P", 6); hashLetras.put("V", 7); 
        hashLetras.put("G", 7); hashLetras.put("H", 7); hashLetras.put("Q", 7); hashLetras.put("B", 8); hashLetras.put("F", 8); 
        hashLetras.put("Z", 8); hashLetras.put("J", 9); hashLetras.put("X", 9); hashLetras.put("K", 9); hashLetras.put("W", 10);
        hashLetras.put("Y", 10);hashLetras.put(" ", 6);//espaco

        int count=0;

        for(int i=0; i<frase.length();i++){

            if( i<(frase.length()-1) && frase.charAt(i)=='Q' && frase.charAt(i+1)=='U'){
                 count = count+8;
                 i++;
            }else{
                String c = frase.charAt(i)+ "";
                count = count+hashLetras.get(c);
            }
        }

        return "O tempo foi de: "+count;
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Ajustando conforme sua dúvida:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String frase1 = "TECNOLOGIA ENVOLVE SERVICO RECURSOS ESTRATEGIA";
    String frase2 = "TECNOLOGIA ENVOLVE SERVICO RECURSOS ESTRATEGIA E AERODINAMICA";

    Integer tempoFrase1 = contaLetras(frase1);
    Integer tempoFrase2 = contaLetras(frase2);

    System.out.println("O tempo da frase 1 foi de: " + tempoFrase1);
    System.out.println("O tempo da frase 2 foi de: " + tempoFrase2);
    System.out.println("O tempo total foi de: " + (tempoFrase1+tempoFrase2));

}

private static Integer contaLetras(String frase) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashLetras=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    hashLetras.put("A", 2); hashLetras.put("E", 3); hashLetras.put("O", 3); hashLetras.put("S", 4); hashLetras.put("R", 4); 
    hashLetras.put("I", 4); hashLetras.put("N", 5); hashLetras.put("D", 5); hashLetras.put("M", 5); hashLetras.put("U", 5); 
    hashLetras.put("T", 6); hashLetras.put("C", 6); hashLetras.put("L", 6); hashLetras.put("P", 6); hashLetras.put("V", 7); 
    hashLetras.put("G", 7); hashLetras.put("H", 7); hashLetras.put("Q", 7); hashLetras.put("B", 8); hashLetras.put("F", 8); 
    hashLetras.put("Z", 8); hashLetras.put("J", 9); hashLetras.put("X", 9); hashLetras.put("K", 9); hashLetras.put("W", 10);
    hashLetras.put("Y", 10);hashLetras.put(" ", 6);//espaco

    int count=0;

    for(int i=0; i<frase.length();i++){

        if( i<(frase.length()-1) && frase.charAt(i)=='Q' && frase.charAt(i+1)=='U'){
             count = count+8;
             i++;
        }else{
            String c = frase.charAt(i)+ "";
            count = count+hashLetras.get(c);
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: se ajudou? vc não tem ideia rsrs. Muitíssimo obrigada

Comment: só uma pergunta, se eu quiser somar todos esses tempos: tentei assim, mas não deu certo. soma = soma + count;
        System.out.println("eee"+ soma);

Comment: Você muda o método contaLetras de String para Integer, devolve apenas o count e remove o texto. No método main, você faz a conta. :)
Eu editei a resposta p/ você verificar.

Comment: Eu tou é no chão com tanta inteligência. Obrigada mais uma vez